# How to use Guice's AssistedInject?

Tags: java, guice, guice-3

I've read https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/AssistedInject, but it doesn't say how to pass in the values of the AssistedInject arguments. What would the injector.getInstance() call look like?

Comment: related, the answers below are not covering cases where he same type is used multiple times. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23553865/using-assisted-inject-with-multiple-params-of-same-type-named-params

Answer (score 203, accepted):

Check the javadoc of [FactoryModuleBuilder](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/google/inject/assistedinject/FactoryModuleBuilder.html) class.

`AssistedInject` allows you to dynamically configure `Factory` for class instead of coding it by yourself. This is often useful when you have an object that has a dependencies that should be injected and some parameters that must be specified during creation of object.

Example from the documentation is a `RealPayment`

```
public class RealPayment implements Payment {
   @Inject
   public RealPayment(
      CreditService creditService,
      AuthService authService,
      @Assisted Date startDate,
      @Assisted Money amount) {
     ...
   }
 }
```

See that `CreditService` and `AuthService` should be injected by container but startDate and amount should be specified by a developer during the instance creation.

So instead of injecting a `Payment` you are injecting a `PaymentFactory` with parameters that are marked as `@Assisted` in `RealPayment`

```
public interface PaymentFactory {
    Payment create(Date startDate, Money amount);
}
```

And a factory should be binded

```
install(new FactoryModuleBuilder()
     .implement(Payment.class, RealPayment.class)
     .build(PaymentFactory.class));
```

Configured factory can be injected in your classes.

```
@Inject
PaymentFactory paymentFactory;
```

and used in your code

```
Payment payment = paymentFactory.create(today, price);
```

Comment: Sought a lot and couldn't find a more concise and clear explanation to my doubts. Many thanks

Comment: This is easier to understand than the documentation on Github. Well done.

Comment: Github documentation is crap as compared to this.

Comment: Shouldn't 'date' and 'amount' be passed along in the method call to 'Payment' ? Why should they be injected here in the constructor ?

Comment: For those who wonder, `RealPayment` does not need to implement an interface.

Comment: Filed a github issue to improve their docs using this answer - https://github.com/google/guice/issues/1287

Comment: just curious, what happens if we add @Singleton annotation on RealPayment class?