# Using @Assisted inject with multiple params of same Type (@Named params)

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice, assisted-inject

my problem boils down to using @Assisted with two string arguments to the factory. The problem is that because Guice treats type as the identification mechanism for parameters, both parameters are the same, and I get a configuration error.

Some Code:

```
public class FilePathSolicitingDialog {

    //... some fields

    public static interface Factory {
        public FilePathSolicitingDialog make(Path existingPath,
                                             String allowedFileExtension,
                                             String dialogTitle);
    }

    @Inject
    public FilePathSolicitingDialog(EventBus eventBus,
                                    SelectPathAndSetTextListener.Factory listenerFactory,
                                    FilePathDialogView view,
                                    @Assisted Path existingPath,
                                    @Assisted String allowedFileExtension,
                                    @Assisted String dialogTitle) {
        //... typical ctor, this.thing = thing
    }

    // ... methods
}
```

The problem lies in the double-strings parameters.

I've tried tagging each string with separate @Named("as appropriate") annotations, but that just leads to more configuration errors. From the sound of those errors they don't want binding annotations on the factory class, so I have not tried custom binding annotations.

The simple and noisy solution is to create a simple argument class to contain those three assisted values, and simply inject that:

```
    public static class Config{
        private final Path existingPath;
        private final String allowedFileExtension;
        private final String dialogTitle;

        public Config(Path existingPath, String allowedFileExtension, String dialogTitle){
            this.existingPath = existingPath;
            this.allowedFileExtension = allowedFileExtension;
            this.dialogTitle = dialogTitle;
        }
    }

    public static interface Factory {
        public FilePathSolicitingDialogController make(Config config);
    }

    @Inject
    public FilePathSolicitingDialogController(EventBus eventBus,
                                              SelectPathAndSetTextListener.Factory listenerFactory,
                                              FilePathDialogView view,
                                              @Assisted Config config) {
        //reasonably standard ctor, some this.thing = thing
        // other this.thing = config.thing
    }
}
```

This works and is likely to be fairly bug-free but is noisy. Some way to get rid of that nested static class would be nice.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Have a look at [this documentation](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/assistedinject/FactoryModuleBuilder.html) (previously [here](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/assistedinject/FactoryProvider.html)):

> **Making parameter types distinct**
>
> The types of the factory method's parameters must be distinct. To use
>   multiple parameters of the same type, use a named `@Assisted` annotation
>   to disambiguate the parameters. The names must be applied to the
>   factory method's parameters:
>
> ```
> public interface PaymentFactory {
>    Payment create(
>        @Assisted("startDate") Date startDate,
>        @Assisted("dueDate") Date dueDate,
>        Money amount);
>  }
> ```
>
> ...and to the concrete type's constructor parameters:
>
> ```
> public class RealPayment implements Payment {
>    @Inject
>    public RealPayment(
>       CreditService creditService,
>       AuthService authService,
>       @Assisted("startDate") Date startDate,
>       @Assisted("dueDate") Date dueDate,
>       @Assisted Money amount) {
>      ...
>    }
>  }
> ```

Comment: Thanks. Worked successfully on GoogleGuice v4. (this answer is valid as of 24/04/2018)